# Laravel last batch job stays in pending

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Description:
I have several servers on which job is performing search to receive results. When I add new server to database I need to perform search for each existing user. Every search is a single job. I decided to use Laravel's batch to group these jobs. Code looks like this:

```
function serverAdded() {
  $batch = Bus::batch([])
    ->allowFailures()
    ->catch(function() { ... })
    ->then(function() { ... })
    ->dispatch();

    $users = User::lazy();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
      $batch->add(new SeearchJob($user));
    }
 }
```

Problem:
The problem is that sometimes 1 job (always the last one) stays in pending state as shown in the attached picture. In logs from job I can see that job is executed correctly. If searching goes wrong I mark job as failed and retrying all failed jobs, but this job is neither finished or failed...

Any ideas?

[image: Pending batch job]

Comment: Did you find a cause or a solution? I'm stuck with something similar. Difference is the "problematic" job is not last for me, but always alone.